# Error printing plot extracted from SQLite blob

Tags: r, sqlite, ggplot2

I have a workflow where I need to generate some data in R, generate plots for the data, save the plots, then render them later. I am using SQLite for this. It works fine, but only for `ggplot2` plots. When I try to save and re-render base R plots, it does not work. Any ideas? Using R version 3.3.0. Here is my code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("RSQLite")

# test data
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50, 1, 6), y = rnorm(50, 1, 8))

# make ggplot
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

# make base plot
pdf("test.pdf") # need open graphics device to record plot headlessly
dev.control(displaylist="enable")
plot(dat)
p <- serialize(recordPlot(), NULL)
dev.off()

# make data frame for db insertion
df1 <- data.frame(baseplot = I(list(p)), ggplot = I(list(serialize(g, NULL))))

# setup db
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbGetQuery(con, 'create table graphs (baseplot blob, ggplot blob)')

# insert the data
dbGetPreparedQuery(con, 'insert into graphs (baseplot, ggplot) values (:baseplot, :ggplot)', 
                   bind.data=df1)

# get the data back out
df2 <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from graphs")

# print the ggplot; not sure why I need 'lapply' for this to work...
lapply(df2[["ggplot"]][1], "unserialize")

# print the base plot
lapply(df2[["baseplot"]][1], "unserialize")
# Error: NULL value passed as symbol address
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to record my findings: I cannot say why this is happening, but this is not related to `sqlite`. The same error occurs right after serializing the plot:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50, 1, 6), y = rnorm(50, 1, 8))

pdf("test.pdf") # need open graphics device to record plot headlessly
dev.control(displaylist="enable")
plot(dat)
p <- serialize(recordPlot(), NULL)
dev.off()

unserialize(p) # !! Error: NULL value passed as symbol address
```

Comment: which version of R are you using? I had the same issue, I think I fixed it by using a more recent version of R

Comment: @user5359531 I am using R 3.5.0 on Linux.

Comment: I think I fixed that error by simply restarting the R session, clearing all plots in RStudio, and trying again. Its noted [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200661423-Error-NULL-value-passed-as-symbol-address-Graphics-error-Plot-rendering-error-) and [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200659547--Error-NULL-value-passed-as-symbol-address-on-package-reload). I think its just a random R/RStudio glitch? Not sure that its directly tied to this situation.

Comment: @user5359531 For me this happens also without RStudio.